# How many jobs were created during Obama's presidency?

Tags: united-states, barack-obama, employment

This report on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobs_created_during_U.S._presidential_terms) seemed to indicate that about 11 million jobs were created during Obama's term.  But there seems to be some controversy in the numbers, like from [this source](http://money.cnn.com/2016/01/13/news/economy/obama-jobs-state-of-the-union/index.html):  claiming 14 million (from Obama's State of the Union address).

So which is it?  How many jobs were created under Obama?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOTU number was out of the "lies, big lies, and statistics" method of counting - yes, you can find a particular statistics to get that #, but it's quite misleading, both in how it was counted, and what was omitted from the full story.

1. Methodology of what was counted is extremely misleading (cherry picking time period).

   - 14.4 million increase in jobs **is measured against when the job market hit rock bottom in February 2010** to Jan 2016, **not** from the start of Obama's presidency or, even more properly, from the previous peak.

     > If you compare the 2016 number of jobs to the previous jobs peak in January 2008 -- **which is how job growth is normally measured** -- the number of private-sector jobs has increased **just 5.6 million** ([*src: investors.com*](http://www.investors.com/politics/commentary/how-good-is-job-growth-the-chart-obama-doesnt-want-you-to-see/)).
     >
     > The United States has only added about **9.3 million jobs** during his term -- from the time Obama took office in January 2009 through December 2015 (*[src: CNN Money](http://money.cnn.com/2016/01/13/news/economy/obama-jobs-state-of-the-union/)*).
2. Absolute numbers of job creation don't really tell the full story.

   - **Absolute # isn't scaled to labor force growth**.

     > There were 143.1 million jobs in 2015. That's ten times more than the 31.5 million positions in 1939 ([*src*](https://www.thebalance.com/job-creation-by-president-by-number-and-percent-3863218))

     As per BLS data (via [ri.gov](http://www.dlt.ri.gov/lmi/laus/us/usadj.htm)), the average labor force growth in US has been ~4.7% per presidential term, or 9.62% per 2 terms. So, Obama's number (be it 14M or 9.3M or 5.6M) should be adjusted 9.6% down to normalize to GW Bush, and further to normalize to earlier presidents. You need to adjust by 19% down to compare to Clinton, and **by 39%** to compare to Reagan's #s.

     So, if you use Reagan as yardstick, as the last major recession recovery, Obama's #s need to be adjusted to 5.8M jobs since start of term (compared to [Reagan's 16M](http://www.forbes.com/sites/kylesmith/2014/09/11/sorry-obama-fans-reagan-did-better-on-jobs-and-growth/#6254f8eb3c92)) and 3.5M jobs since last peak (and even the extremely misleading 14M becomes 8.8M - compared to Reagan's 20M since trough).

     In all fairness, Obama's #s are for 7 years, not 8 full years. So, let's add a [projected 2.1M](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/empsit.nr0.htm) for 2016, and we get:

     ```
     | Measurement (M)  | Reagan | Obama           | Obama (2016#) |
     | Since ...        |        | (scale to 1988) |               |
     +------------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
     | Peak (01/2008)   | ?      | 4.85            | 5.6+2.1=7.7   |
     | Term (1/2009)    | 16     | 7.18            | 9.3+2.1=11.4  |
     | Term low (2/2010)| 20     | 10.4            | 14.4+2.1=16.5 |
     ```

     This normalization can also be captured in the number known as **Employment to Population ratio** (graphs [from Wash.Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2014/09/09/so-which-president-was-best-at-creating-jobs-anyway/?utm_term=.c967e4a9ae76)):

     [image]

     [image]
   - More importantly, **Labor force participation dropped from 65.7% to 62.7%** under Obama, [according to BLS](https://data.bls.gov/timeseries/LNS11300000), due to large numbers of people dropping out of labor force.

     [image]
3. Absolute numbers of job creation don't really tell the full story because they don't specify what kinds of jobs.

   Specifically, under Obama, a far larger share of jobs created were **part time, and/or low-wage jobs**.

   > It’s true that since 2007, job growth has come from a large range of fairly low-wage sectors. The food and drinking services industry, which includes most bars and restaurants, has grown by 17% — while average weekly pay in this industry is only $339 a week. Home-health care services — mostly home-health aides — has grown by an astonishing 48%, but the average weekly pay is only $548
   >   *[Source: WSJ blog](http://blogs.wsj.com/economics/2016/05/11/just-how-good-or-bad-are-all-the-jobs-added-to-the-economy-since-the-recession/)*
   >
   > But job losses and gains have been skewed. Higher-wage industries — like accounting and legal work — shed 3.6 million positions during the recession and have added only 2.6 million positions during the recovery. But lower-wage industries lost two million jobs, then added 3.8 million. (*[Source: New York Times, 2014](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/28/business/economy/recovery-has-created-far-more-low-wage-jobs-than-better-paid-ones.html?_r=0)*)

   And that was reflected in lower pay

   > As a result, the average household’s take-home pay has declined through the recession and the recovery to $51,017 in 2012 from $55,627 in 2007, after adjusting for inflation. (*NYT*)
4. Saying "During Obama's Presidency" creates an impression that it was attributable to Obama, as opposed to **other factors that had nothing to do with him**.

   - Generally, economy adds more jobs coming out of a recession. It's not president specific, and was true of both parties.

     > those who inherited a recession, like Clinton, Obama, Reagan, Carter, and LBJ, did better at job creation ([src](https://www.thebalance.com/job-creation-by-president-by-number-and-percent-3863218)).
   - Most experts indicate that President doesn't actually influence private sector job growth as much as other factors: business cycle, economic fundamentals, monetary policy (Obama benefitted from Federal Reserve's zero interest rates and QE measures), etc...
5. To answer a somewhat-unasked "where did 14M and 11M figures came from":

   As you can see from bullet #3 and the table there:

   - 14M was the misleading number of jobs added since the low (2010) till Dec 2015, cited in Obama's SOTU.
   - 11M is the # of jobs projected to be for full Obama's term.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'm also glad you added point 4.  Presidents have very little direct influence on the economy, no matter what the campaign trail makes it sound like.  At best, a cooperative Congress can follow the President's budgetary/tax lead.

Comment: @Bobson - there's *some* effect, but not nearly as much as everyone seems to believe.

Comment: @Bobson  If either of you  think that the current form of the question gives too much credit to Obama (or whatever president), you should have seen it before I edited it.  Note that presidents do have some influence on monetary policy, as they appoint some of the members of the Federal Reserve board of governors.  The ironic part is that they appoint the chair about two years into their terms.  So (for example) Reagan's choice (Greenspan) had more influence after Reagan's term.  He inherited and reappointed Carter's choice (Volcker).  Obama had Bush's choice (Bernanke) for six years.

Comment: @Bobson better?

Comment: Small quibble as I enjoyed this answer thoroughly, the 11 million figure is net job (not absolute) creation according to their methodology on Wikipedia.  People forget that George W. Bush inherited a recession as well (the Nasdaq declined 70%!). And one could easily argue that the Keynesian policies under Bernanke and Yellen hindered job creation, not helped it.

Comment: Finally fiscal policy obviously has an effect, as do other economic variables.  One of the policy choices that hurt Obama was the sheer number of the extensions of unemployment benefits.  Study after study shows that a large subset of those out of work won't go looking for work  until their benefits run out (or turn from black market, under the table jobs).

Comment: This answer provides a lot of good economic context, but I think there are a few things left out that leave the wrong impression in some places. The trend in labor force participation is a lot more complex than "rose under previous presidents and declined under Obama". Labor force participation has been declining for decades, and though the recession accelerated that, it has since been stable for well over a year.

Comment: Second, data from 2012 about median wages are a little out of date. We saw wage growth in 2015 for the first time in a long while. Third, though it is of course true that Presidents have little control over economic and employment growth, it's worth noting that a nontrivial portion of employment growth can be tied directly to policies Obama advocated. In particular, the CBO found that the ARRA likely created over a million jobs.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't do a good job of answering the question. The question is "how many jobs were created" not "how many jobs was President Obama responsible for creating".